# Function prototype in template using a templated type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, functional-programming, std

I would like to understand why this fails :

```
template <class T, class U>
T apply(U stuff, std::function<T (U)> function) { return function(stuff); }
```

(This is not a real code of course).

On g++-4.8, I get "template argument 1 is invalid".

Thanks !

---

Edit: thorough example : 
Basically, what I want to do is to enforce a particular prototype for the `MapFunction` and `ReductionFunction` types.

I would like:

- MapFunction : typeof(*InputIterator) -> T
- ReductionFunction : (T, T) -> T

Code:

```
template <class T, class InputIterator, class ReductionFunction>
T mapReduce_n(InputIterator in, 
    unsigned int size, 
    T baseval, 
    std::function<T (decltype(*InputIterator))> map, 
    ReductionFunction reduce)
{
    T val = baseval;

    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        T map_val = baseval;

        #pragma omp for nowait
        for (auto i = 0U; i < size; ++i)
        {
            map_val = reduce(map_val, map(*(in + i)));
        }

        #pragma omp critical
        val = reduce(val, map_val);
    }

    return val;
}
```

---

Edit 2 :

I think that the `std::function<T (decltype(*InputIterator))> map` part,  is wrong, it should be :
`std::function<T (decltype(*in))> map`.

However this fails with :

```
mismatched types 'std::function<T(decltype (* in))>' and 'double (*)(std::complex<double>)'
```

I also tried iterator traits :

```
std::function<T (std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type)> map
```

But it fails with :

```
type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 
'template<class _Signature> class std::function'

error:   expected a type, got '(T)(std::iterator_traits<_II>::value_type)'
```

---

Third edit:

Another trial, I think I start getting close!

```
std::function<T (typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type)> map
```

Fails with :

```
mismatched types 
'std::function<T (typename std::iterator_traits<_II>::value_type)>' 
and 
'double (*)(std::complex<double>)'
```

Here is my call :

```
MathUtil::mapReduce_n(
   in, // const std::complex<double> * const
   conf.spectrumSize(), // unsigned int
   0.0, 
   MathUtil::CplxToPower, // double CplxToPower(const std::complex<double> val);
   std::plus<double>())
```

Comment: [This does not fail](http://ideone.com/6dyr3e). Please post actual code that fails.

Comment: You're not showing any `std::function` in the edited code. Post the code *that fails,* not the code "before the failing modifications."

Comment: Sorry. I modified to reflect what I ideally want.

Comment: I recomend you to use [`std::forward()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) to get perfect forwarding in the function call.

Comment: @Manu343726, I don't know where you could use `forward<>()` properly in this function.  It looks to me like all the arguments are used multiple times in loops or parallel calls, so none of them could tolerate pilfering (since `forward<T>()` either transforms into effectively a harmless pass-thru or a `move()` depending on `T`).

Comment: Edited to reflect new trials.

Answer (score 2):

I'd think you get answers faster if you'd provide a minimalist example showing the problem rather than embedding the problem into a fairly large amount of code making the problem harder to see. Also, editing the post can amount to *reducing* the text, removing irrelevant material. As far as I see the problem, you want to pass a `std::function<Signature>` object which can consume the values provided by an iterator. What you tried basically amounts to this (you didn't post a complete example although you posted unrelated snippets of code):

```
template <typename T, typename Iterator>
void f(Iterator it, T value, std::function<T(decltype(*it))> fun);

double fun(std::complex<double>);
int main() {
    std::complex<double> values[1];
    f(values, 0.0, fun);
}
```

This code tries to deduce `T` from the second and the third argument. However, it fails because the third argument isn't of the expected form, i.e., it is not a `std::function<Signature>`. Instead, the type of the third argument is `double(*)(std::complex<T double>)`. A work-around could be to pass an argument of the correct type and this, indeed, matches the function template:

f(values, 0.0, std::function)>(fun));

Of course, this isn't too pretty and makes `f()` harder to use than necessary. A better solution is to get an implicit conversion and not have the third argument participate in template argument deduction. The easiest way to do that is to not mention `T` directly:

```
template <typename T>
struct hide_type
{
    typedef T type;
};

template <typename T, typename Iterator>
void f(Iterator it,
       T        ,
       std::function<typename hide_type<T>::type(decltype(*it))>);
```

Using a type nested inside `hide_type<T>` results in `T` not being deducible from the third argument and, instead, an implicit conversion possibly being attempted if the third argument doesn't match the type. Finally, you had problems using `value_type` to specify the argument. Although the argument to the function isn't really the problem, you can use `value_type`, too, but you need to use it with `typename` to indicate that the dependent name `value_type` is a type:

```
template <typename T, typename Iterator>
void f(Iterator it,
       T        ,
       std::function<typename hide_type<T>::type(typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type>);
```

The signature still needs to be formulated in a way which doesn't cause it to be considered for template argument deduction.